# Selecting data where fields matches

Tags: mysql, sql

So, i have this table structure

```
+----+---------+-----------+---------+------+---------------------+
| id | to_user | from_user | message | read | sent                |
+----+---------+-----------+---------+------+---------------------+
|  1 |      2  |        1  | test    |    0 | 2012-01-11 13:20:14 |
+----+---------+-----------+---------+------+---------------------+
```

And as you can see i use this for very simple chat, and now what i wanna do is get the list of each conversations. So i need to find a way of selecting **one** last message from conversation which each user. so i need something like

```
   select * 
   from `messages` 
   where `to_user` = 2 --(this is my user id)
          and `to_user` = `from_user` 
   LIMIT 1
```

Now i know that `LIMIT` would always return 1 record and other logic is probably not so good, anyways if anyone get's what i want here, could help me a little :)

Comment: If you are going to have multiple "chat" sessions going on, I would suggest revising your query to identify a chat session.  What if "from_user" is chatting with 2-3 people, and so is "to_user".  how would you know which was the latest chat element from a person to a given to the correct chat session they were chatting with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `IN()` subquery selects the `id` of each row having the most recent `sent` between two users. The outer query selects the remaining columns for each `id` returned from the subquery.

#### Update fixed the HAVING clause...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM table GROUP BY to_user, from_user HAVING sent = MAX(sent)
);
```